# What is the best way to map the JSON Object from a JDBC result set in vert.x to a Java/Groovy class(es)?

Tags: groovy, vert.x

If I have a block of code similar to below:

```
conn.queryWithParams("select * from my_user where user_id = ?", params, { queryRes ->
                    if (queryRes.succeeded()) {
                        ResultSet rs = queryRes.result()
                        def objects = rs.getRows()
                        def user = new User()
                        def jsonObjectFromDB = objects.get(0)
                        user.userId = jsonObjectFromDB.getLong("user_id")

                        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(200).end(Json.encode(user))
                    } else {
                        // query failed
                        println "QUERY FAILED"
                        throw queryRes.cause()
                    }
                })
```

Instead of doing this for every field of the user object:

```
user.userId = jsonObjectFromDB.getLong("user_id")
```

Is there a nicer more vert.x way of taking all the values from the DB and putting them into their corresponding object?

Comment: Can't you just use http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/Json.html to  `decodeValue` the json string to an instance?

Comment: what's wrong with `User user = new User( objects.get( 0 ) )`?

Comment: To clarify, my java/groovy object and it's fields follow java type naming conventions (camel casing) like "userId" and the database uses typical SQL naming conventions like "user_id", so there is a slight variation in the DB to the object. With hibernate there are annotations for this, but I'm not sure what's best here... maybe renaming the columns of the DB is the "better" way in this scenario?

Comment: It's just jackson isn't it?  Annotate your setters (or your `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor parameters if you prefer immutability) with `@JsonProperty("snake_name")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to write a POJO like so:

```
package some.package.or.other;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class User {
    private final String userId;
    private final Integer someOtherValue;

    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("user_id") String userId,
                @JsonProperty("some_other_value") Integer someOtherValue) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.someOtherValue = someOtherValue;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Integer getSomeOtherValue() {
        return someOtherValue;
    }
}
```

then, you should just be able to call:

```
User user = io.vertx.core.json.Json.decodeValue(json, User.class);
```

And jackson should just sort it out

Comment: Worked great, and does exactly what I was after, thanks!